# How can I combine numbers into strings in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with numbers resembling:

```
df$X1    df$X2

.9     1.442
```

How could I use elements from this data frame to create labels for a confidence intervals that will be nicely formatted string:

```
(0.90, 1.42)
```

I'm lost somewhere between `paste`, `as.character` and `c()` and nothing seems to work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
paste("(",df$X1,",",df$X2,")",sep="")
```

In your example, it looks like you might want to round your numbers, but the rounding is incorrect. Do you want a certain number of digits after the decimal point?

Also, "1" and "2" are frowned upon as names in a data.frame - see `?make.names`

**EDIT:**

To round in cases like this, I like using `formatC()`:

```
paste("(", formatC(df$X1, digits = 2, format = "f"), ",",
  formatC(df$X2, digits = 2, format = "f"), ")", sep = "")
```

However, if there are values less than `.005`, note that they will end up being `0.00`.

Comment: I'd like to round the numbers to two decimal points, irrespectively of their original format. Agree on names in df - they are better in real dataset.

Comment: @radek, Thanks for the clarification. I added a suggestion for rounding above.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to @BenBarnes, I just want to add 1 small point.  In addition to (or in place of) `formatC()` you can use `round(df$X1, digits=2)`.  You may find `round` to be simpler than `formatC()`.  Moreover, this won't have any effect on the status of the output as being character in mode.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to `round()` @gung. The reason I prefer `formatC()` for cases such as this is that the output is meant to be character, and `round(0.10, digits = 2)` returns `0.1` rather than `0.10`, which is what @radek wanted, I think.

Comment: @BenBarnes, that's a good point. I had never played with `round()` to try to get that exact behavior, so I didn't know. (I also didn't know about `formatC()` before reading your answer, but I see that it does work as intended, provided you use the `format="f"` argument specification.)